# How did the word Solicitor come to mean two different professions?

Tags: etymology, american-english

In the US, it's very commonplace to see signs on homes and businesses indicated "No soliciting", which I construe to mean, "Please don't show up just to try and sell us something. We're not interested." I've had friends whom have worked as door-to-door salespeople and as canvassers, both of which would be considered solicitors and not welcome at those locations.

In my work, I occasionally have need to interact with municipalities and their designated attorney, whose position is often titled, "Township Solicitor." Presumably this person is also someone that you don't want to show up at your door as well, but for very different reasons.

Given that these are two very different professions that evoke a very different image, I'm curious how they came to both use the same word.

Comment: I think it's more than two different professions.

Comment: Could you check a dictionary?

Comment: @YosefBaskin Can you clarify? I'm unclear how a dictionary will provide me the etymology of the word coming to have two meanings.

Comment: "...door-to-door salespeople ... would be considered solicitors." No, they are *soliciting* which is rather different. Nobody here (UK) calls a door-to-door salesman a 'solicitor', they are called 'hawkers'.

Comment: @WeatherVane my question is about American English. I don't live in the UK so can't comment on what they are called there.

Comment: As YosefBaskin suggests, [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/solicitor) may have the right answer: both kinds of solicitor could be described as "one who conducts matters on behalf of another". (This is "standard research" on ELU. The question then could be centered on specific foggy points in the source definitions.) Cheers, and welcome!

Comment: I see, Lexico gives [solicitor](https://www.lexico.com/definition/solicitor) with North American usage of that meaning.

Comment: To explain the dictionary suggestion: Most show etymology. If someone asks a question here, we expect that's who will do the heavy lifting, or at least ... some. We get so lazy otherwise. The basic routine is "I looked it up and got ABC, but I am left with XYZ."

Comment: Seems a traveling salesperson, courtroom lawyer, and street hostess all sell a product, an idea, a service. Need a brush, evidence, some company, Professor?

Comment: When I was a kid, my family lived in the top two floors of our house and rented out the ground floor flat. I was a little precocious, and loved to read the local newspaper, the South London Press, especially the "Is your Neighbour in Court?" page which reported low- and medium-level criminal cases in the local courts. At the relevant time the downstairs flat was rented to Mr and Mrs G. I looked up from the courts page and said to my father, 'What is "soliciting"?' He said 'Why do you ask?". I said, "I see here that Mrs G has been fined for it in court". – he shouted "Give me that!"